# rearrange order of spark columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark `dataframe` with many columns. Using **Spark** and **Scala**, I would like to select the columns in a specified order, but I don't want to hardcode the desired order. In pseudo-code, I'd like do something like:

```
val colNames = df.columns

val newOrder = colNames(colNames.length) ++ colNames(0:colNames.length-1)

df.select(newOrder)
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
val df = Seq((1,2,3)).toDF("A","B","C")

df.select(df.columns.last, df.columns.dropRight(1): _*).show

+---+---+---+
|  C|  A|  B|
+---+---+---+
|  3|  1|  2|
+---+---+---+
```